# How can I avoid pausing iOS socket data stream when a phone call is active?

Tags: ios, sockets, wifi, gcdasyncsocket, cellular-network

I have an iOS app, a streaming game, which uses TCP via GCDAsyncSocket.  When connected over WiFi, and there's an incoming call, the game does not pause.  When playing over a cellular network (e.g. Verizon, Virgin), the socket stream pauses until the call ends.

Is there a way to configure the app to keep the stream open/un-paused when calls are received?